# Display an image on JPanel by clicking on a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, border-layout

I just started learning GUI programming and I'm facing a problem to load image.
I wanted to place a JButton on the WEST of BorderLayout, and display the image in the CENTER by clicking on that JButton.

Please refer to this picture:

[image: Please refer to this picture]

The code is as shown below. I've been trying for a few hours but still couldn't make it.

```
public class Testing extends JFrame {
    private JButton btn;
    private JLabel pict;
    private JPanel wpanel,cpanel;
    private BufferedImage image;
    
    Testing(){
        Container cont = getContentPane();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        //add button
        wpanel = new JPanel();
        cpanel = new JPanel();
        btn = new JButton("Click me");
        wpanel.add(btn);
        
        
        //Clicking button to load image
            //inner class
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                try {
                    loadImage();

                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            createAndShowGUI();             
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Couldn't load image.");
                }
            }
        });


        public void loadImage() throws IOException{
            image = ImageIO.read(Testing.class.getResource("/path/.jpg"));
        }

        public void createAndShowGUI(){
            pict = new JLabel();
            pict.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
            cpanel.add(pict);
        }
        //end of clicking button to load image
        
        cont.add(wpanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
        cont.add(cpanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("JFrame"); 
        setSize(300, 300);  
        setVisible(true); 
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            new Testing();  
         }
         
        });
   }

}
```

Comment: You only need to create and show the GUI one time.  After you read the image, you update the JLabel icon.

Comment: That code seen above does not compile even when imports are added, due to methods being declared within the constructor. **General Tips:** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).